# How to stop rendering of a div element in angular during pre-load?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
      <div
        *ngFor="let d of data.data"
        [ngClass]="{ 'key-value': d.alignment === 'left' }"
      >
        <ng-template [ngIf]="d.alignment == 'left'">
```

I want the ng-template with 'right' alignment not to render at all in the loop. So how do I achieve that?

Comment: whats the problem with this code?

Comment: Yeah so how do I stop rendering the content present in ngElse, even during the first render? Like this code will render ngElse right?